# Excel: Store row number in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has 2 columns, the first is a unique identifier, the second is a list delineated by the '|' character of people assigned to that case. I am attempting to write a macro that uses text to columns to break out the second column into multiple columns and then copy them all with the corresponding identifier to the bottom of the original columns. I am dealing with about 46,000 rows, and the result will have around 70,000 I would guess. An example is as follows:

**Original Data**

```
ColumnA ColumnB  
123     Adam | Jill | Bob
456     Brent | Bob | Betsy | Sam
789     Matt | Adam | Jill
```

**Needed Data**

```
ColumnA ColumnB 
123     Adam
456     Brent
789     Matt
123     Jill
456     Bob
789     Adam
123     Bob
456     Betsy
789     Jill
456     Sam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
Sub test()
    Dim inputRng As Range
    Set inputRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    Dim outputRng As Range
    Set outputRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1")

    While inputRng.Value <> ""
        Dim names As Variant
        names = Split(inputRng.Offset(, 1).Value, "|")

        For Each nme In names
            outputRng.Value = inputRng.Value
            outputRng.Offset(, 1).Value = Trim(nme)
            Set outputRng = outputRng.Offset(1)
        Next

        Set inputRng = inputRng.Offset(1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Adjust the inputRng and outputRng to point where you want

All the code does is split the string value in VBA and iterate over that list then move down onto the next row. It keeps going until it finds an empty (Value == "") cell and then stops.

Comment: I think you still need to account for the unique ID for each `inputRng`  row. It needs to be associated with each `outputRng` row.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer... I've tried it out and get nothing, but no errors. I take it I need to do something different with the range?

I was hoping to automatically find the size of the range by counting the number of rows before hitting an empty row on the unique identifier column. I am not sure exactly how to implement it. Something like: 

    CaseCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Comment: Because he's using a `while` loop you don't need to find the last cell explicitly. The loop will just end when it's time to end so long as your data are arranged contiguously.

Comment: I assume the data starts in cell A1 on the first sheet of the workbook the macro is in. The first column should be the IDs and the second column the names. It will write the output back to same sheet starting in cell D1 (the ID in column D, the name in column E)

Comment: JDunkerley, Thanks for your help... 

I've looked through this macro and the structure seems to be exactly what I want to happen, however, when I run it, nothing happens and it does not throw an error. Any thoughts? 

Thanks,
John

Comment: First guess would be that inputRng isn't pointed at the correct location. It should be the top left cell. One quick and dirty way to debug it is to put in 'MSGBOX inputRng.Value' on the line after set inputRng = ... This should return the value if it isnt giving you the top left cell then you need to change the location specified in the SET line to point to the data set